# Deleting many tables when one specific table is deleted in FLASK SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy **VolunteerClient** Model which is a **join table**:

```
class VolunteerClient(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'volunteer_client'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    volunteer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('provider_user.user_id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='RESTRICT'), unique=True)
    client_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='RESTRICT'), unique=True)
```

and a **VolunteerReport** model:

```
class VolunteerReport(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'volunteer_report'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    volunteer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('volunteer_client.volunteer_id', cascade="all, delete"))
    client_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('volunteer_client.client_id', cascade="all, delete"))
    report = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    report_category = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
```

If I was to delete a **VolunteerClient** table, which essentially unassignes a volunteer from a client but does not actually delete the **users** which they represent. with a specific **volunteer_id** and **client_id** set,

**Example:** I delete **VolunteerClient** table where: volunteer_id = 1, & client_id = 1,

I want any and all **VolunteerReports** where: volunteer_id = 1, & client_id = 1 to be deleted as well. Have I set this up correctly with the FK references to **volunteer_client** and the `cascade='all, delete'`?

Any advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically delete child rows when a parent is deleted, you need to set `ondelete='CASCADE'` on the foreign key defined in the child table.  In this case, the foreign key is a *composite* key as it consists of `volunteer_id` and `client_id`.  This means you need a unique constraint over the columns in the parent as well.  This simplified version of your models show how it would work (I've removed the FK definitions from `VolunteerClient` the tables are defined in the question).

```py
class VolunteerClient(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'volunteer_client'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    volunteer_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    client_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    __table_args__ = (sa.UniqueConstraint(volunteer_id, client_id),)


class VolunteerReport(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'volunteer_report'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    volunteer_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    client_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    __table_args__ = (
        sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            [volunteer_id, client_id],
            [VolunteerClient.volunteer_id, VolunteerClient.client_id],
            ondelete='CASCADE',
        ),
    )
```

You can also configure [delete cascades](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#delete) on SQLAlchemy [relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationships.html), which give you more control over what happens when a parent row is deleted.  As you don't seem to be using relationships, and the database cascade does what you want I won't cover that in this answer.

Comment: looking above in my VolunteerReport table I have unique=True defined on the model. Is that not setting the unique constraint you mentioned above?

Comment: You need to have a single constraint that matches the foreign key, otherwise you will get an error about a foreign key mismatch.